# How can I write additional text directly beneath"normal" text with CSS?

Tags: css

I am trying to create an HTML document that should look something like

```
Some text that spans multiple rows
4    4    4    5     8        4        

but that has some statistical information
3   4    3   4    11          12                      

beneath almost every word
7       6      5     4
```

I have tried something like

```
<span>Some<br>4</span>
<span>text<br>4</span>...
```

and

```
<style>
  table {display:inline}
</style>

...

<table><tr><td>some</td><td>4</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>text</td><td>4</td></tr></table>
```

both of which didn't give me the desired result.

So, can I solve this problem with CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
<p>
  <span>Foo<span class="stat">3</span></span>
  <span>Bar<span class="stat">3</span></span>
</p>

p {
  line-height: 2em;
}

span {
  position: relative;
}

span.stat {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 1em;
}
```

That's going to be quite a lot of markup... O_O;;

Comment: This is almost what I am after, but the problem is after the line wraps, because on the second line, Text will overwrite .stat (at least in FF).

Comment: @René See updated answer, fiddle around with the exact values yourself. :)

Comment: deceze: I really appreciate your help, but I don't have any <p> in my text, nor do I want some, because I want the browser to determine the "line breaks" depending on the display width of the browser.

Comment: In that case, set the line-height on the body (or whatever the parent element is).

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
<tr><td>some</td><td>text</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The problem with the 'table approach' is that the line-breaks must be determined before hand, but I'd like the text to be line-broken on the browser side, depending on the width of the screen.

Comment: How about this then:
    <style>div {float: left}</style>
    <div>some<br />4</div>
    <div>text<br />5</div>

Answer (score 1):

You could try using lists:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Some<br/>4
  </li>
  <li>
    text<br/>4
  </li>
  ....
</ul>
```

The list items will each contain a word plus a digit below. Long texts will wrap to several lines keeping the structure.

Answer (score 1):

While this question already has an accepted answer, it might be worth considering an alternative. I will offer, in advance, that this isn't necessarily cross browser (I don't imagine that IE < 8 will do much with it for example) compatible.

Assuming the markup of:

```
<p class="statisticText"><span title="4">Some</span> <span title="5">text</span> <span title="2">with</span> <span title="1">associated</span> <span title="1">information</span>.</p>
```

The following css should approximate what you're trying to achieve:

```
p.statisticText {line-height: 2em; }

p.statisticText span {position: relative; top: -0.75em; }

p.statisticText span:before {content: attr(title); position: absolute; top: 1em; left: 0; }
```

I've not experimented to present it as you'd like, but just in case you'd like an alternative option, with a little less mark-up (but not by much). And, of course, don't mind considering something that's restricted to compliant browsers...

Comment: Very clever, albeit really not very compatible. :)

Comment: @deceze, why thank you =) I must confess that I, biased though I clearly am, prefer my approach. But must also agree that, outside of peculiarly advanced internet users, it isn't much use as yet. *Damn you, Internet Explorer, damn you..!* and so forth... =b

Answer (score 0):

A table is probably the sensible solution, and will guarantee correct alignment in all browsers. You need to 1) decide how many words N you want on a line (this determines the number of columns in your table), 2) divide up the text you want to render into N word chunks, then 3) Populate every other row in the table with the chunked text, and the rows in between with the stats.

**Edit:** just seen your comment re wanting to let the browser control words per line. In that case i think the <li> solution from Developer Art is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="lefty">Some<br/>4</div>
<div class="lefty">Text<br/>10</div>
```

```
.lefty{float:left;}
```